# How to find the width of text when font weight is bold?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

I am trying to draw border for text. I have done it for all dynamic font size. But when font weight is **bold** or **bolder**, width of the text is changes for each font size and it overlaps the border.

My code is as follows,

```
<svg id="container_svg" style="width: 1000px; height: 630px;">
   <rect id="container_svg_SvgRect" x="1" y="1" width="996" height="626" fill="transparent" opacity="0.3" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></rect>
   <rect id="container_svg_ChartArea" x="83" y="96" width="893" height="418" fill="transparent" stroke-width="0.5" opacity="0.3" stroke="Gray"></rect>
   <rect id="container_svg_ChartTitleBorder" x="220.5" y="18.349999999999994" rx="5" ry="5" width="581" height="39.6" fill="lightblue" stroke-width="0.8" stroke="red" opacity="0.8"></rect>
   <g id="container_svg_ChartTitle">
   <text id="container_svg_ChartTitle" x="230.5" y="48.05" fill="#E27F2D" font-size="33px" font-family="Arial" font-style="italic" font-weight="bold" opacity="1" letter-spacing="-0.7px" text-anchor="start">title is my title border which is overflow </text>
</svg>
```

Here I've tried to adjust the font weight. But when font size increases, text is overflowing on rectangle.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvuhktet/) :

Answer (score 2):

Get the length of the text via the SVG DOM and adjust the rect width.

```js
document.getElementById("container_svg_ChartTitleBorder").width.baseVal.value = document.getElementById("svg_ChartTitle").getComputedTextLength() + 20
```

```html
<svg id="container_svg" style="width: 1000px; height: 630px;">
<rect id="container_svg_SvgRect" x="1" y="1" width="996" height="626" fill="transparent" opacity="0.3" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"></rect>
<rect id="container_svg_ChartArea" x="83" y="96" width="893" height="418" fill="transparent" stroke-width="0.5" opacity="0.3" stroke="Gray"></rect>
<rect id="container_svg_ChartTitleBorder" x="220.5" y="18.349999999999994" rx="5" ry="5" width="581" height="39.6" fill="lightblue" stroke-width="0.8" stroke="red" opacity="0.8"></rect>
<g id="container_svg_ChartTitle">
<text id="svg_ChartTitle" x="230.5" y="48.05" fill="#E27F2D" font-size="33px" font-family="Arial" font-style="italic" font-weight="bold" opacity="1" letter-spacing="-0.7px" text-anchor="start">title is my title border which is overflow </text>
</svg>
```